# Next.js - module not found when importing TypeScript module

Tags: typescript, next.js, es6-modules

Here's my code:

```
// lib/test2.ts

export function test2() {
  console.log("test2");
}
```

```
// pages/index.tsx

import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
// works
import { test } from "../lib/test.js";
// error
import { test2 } from "../lib/test2.js";

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({
  req,
}): Promise<{ props: {} }> => {
  test();
  test2();
  return { props: {} };
};

export default function Home(props: {}) {
  return <div>Hi</div>;
}
```

When I run this code, I get

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '../lib/test2.js' in '/Users/USER/Documents/software/nextjs-test/pages'
```

I'm not sure why. Shouldn't `lib/test2.ts` compile to `lib/test2.js`, and the import should be fine? I suppose I'm not very familiar with how the imports actually get resolved when TypeScript is in the mix.

Link to all the code here: https://github.com/arcticmatt/nextjs-test

Comment: Did you mean that "*`import { test2 } from "../lib/test2.ts";` works*" (`.ts` instead of `.js`)? Otherwise I can't see the difference between these import styles.

Comment: @Bergi there's no difference in import styles. The difference is that `test.js` is actually a file. `test2.js` doesn't exist, `test2.ts` exists. Looking at the source code might make it clearer

Comment: Are you saying that `test.js` is written in JavaScript and `test2.ts` is written in TypeScript? You haven't posted a snippet with the contents of `test.js`, that's what's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the gist of what's happening.

webpack is throwing a `ModuleNotFoundError` in [`Compilation.js`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/Compilation.js).

The reason is because webpack is the thing that actually compiles TypeScript to JavaScript. This [post](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/webpack/typescript) provides a decent explanation.

If you add

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    console.log(config);
    config.module.rules.map((rule) => console.log(JSON.stringify(rule)));
    return config;
  },
};
```

to `next.config.js`, you can see the webpack config that Next.js uses. Apparently they use the `next-babel-loader` to compile TypeScript to JavaScript before bundling it.

In, summary, what's happening is:

1. webpack tries to find `../lib/test2.js` in `Compilation.js`. This is before anything has been compiled to JavaScript.
2. `../lib/test2.js` doesn't exist, since `../lib/test2.ts` hasn't been compiled to JavaScript yet.
3. An error is thrown.

**The solution is to omit the file extension and write `import { test2 } from "../lib/test2";`**. You can clone the repo I linked in the OP and run `yarn dev` to verify this works.

Comment: So, what was the solution?

Comment: Just ran into this myself as well, +1 for what's the solution :)

Comment: However, this directly contradicts TypeScript advice to always include the .js file extension in imports ...? https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40878

Answer (score -1):

Just install the `babel` packages and you are good to go. Details here https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader.

`npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack`